# compare values from two dataframes and score results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one is a sample data from exam test where students were asked to looked at chest X-ray image and  enter results from different variables to determine if the patient has pneumonia. Here is how the dataset for the test looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Name": ['Phillip', 'Donald', 'Fankhola', 'Mixo', 'Delight', 'Vuyo'],
        "image_code": ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006'],
       "image_quality_test": [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1],
       "consolidation_right_test": [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

**image_code** represent different images they looked at.

**image_quality_test** , the code means **1** for *Adequat*e, **2** for *sub-optimal* and **3** for *uninterpretable*.

**condolidation_right_test** , the codes means **1** is *yes* and **0** for *No*.

Now, I have second dataframe with right results to be used as marking scheme. It looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = {
        "image_code": ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006'],
       "image_quality_test": [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       "consolidation_right_test": [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
       }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2
```

Now I need help to compare table one results to table two then score per students so that I can show how each student performed on each image test.

I started writing code then got stuck after noticing I dont have a better way of approaching this.

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

students_df= data

marking_scheme_df = data2


students_df.image_quality_test.value_counts()

students_df.groupby(['name'])['image_quality_test'].value_counts()
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @not_speshal visualization of scores of students per image or colour coded table with scores

Comment: Please include your expected output as a table. How do you expect to compare `df` and `df2`?